# Is there any reason to not turn null check after malloc into a function?

Tags: c, syntax, malloc

In `C` when we use the `malloc` family functions we should add a conditional to check if the allocation succeeded and if not, to print a message.

If I have many allocations in my code, is there any reason why I shouldn't make this a function? i.e:

```
void nullcheck(void * x){
    if (x == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation has failed");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

and calling the function:

```
int * a = malloc(sizeof(int));
nullcheck(a);
```

It makes the code nicer and shorter, is there any reason why it shouldn't be done?

Comment: you will leak memory from previous calls to `malloc`.

Comment: Some times, calling `exit` as a result of a failed memory allocation is not a desirable strategy. For example, one application may prefer logging the error, and being able to continue doing other things.

Comment: @mch: If you're exiting the program completely then that's not likely of much concern.

Comment: Often you'd want to do some cleaning before exiting the program (close open files, sockets...). Hot `exit(1)` inside a function prevents you from doing so.

Comment: ... You can use `atexit` to register that stuff

Comment: Watch out if you start combining this pattern with any IPC mechanisms other than sockets.   Including, but not limited to: `flock` or `lockf` locks, POSIX or SysV shared memory and message queues, SysV semaphores, any synchronization objects in shared memory.  There can actually be some problems with sockets too, but it's much less likely to cause deadlock than other IPC mechanisms.

Comment: before calling exit(), need to free any previously allocated memory, close any open files, etc.  so this proposed function will not be adequate for almost any scenario.  suggest: initialize the pointer to NULL, then wrap the call to malloc() in an 'if' statement that checks the returned value for null, immediately calls perror() to log the problem, cleans up the environment (prior mallocs, open files, etc) then if appropriate call exit()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do everything in one function?

```
void *unrecoverable_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *x = malloc(size);

    if (x) {
        return x;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation has failed.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

While the `x = malloc(); if (!x) { /* recover */ }` pattern is pretty common (and good practice), recovering from an OOM state is extremely difficult.  It gives you a warm and fuzzy feeling checking for the allocation failure, but in a sufficiently complex application whatever you do to recover probably isn't going to work anyway.

Comment: This assumes that `fprintf` isn't going to internally allocate any memory, but whatever.

Comment: Very nice, any reason why `fprintf` instead of `printf`?

Comment: About "whatever you do to recover probably isn't going to work anyway" do you mean that it won't matter to do it like in your answer over the usual way because OOM is so hard to recover from?

Comment: What I mean - and I'm sure it is a controversial opinion - is that checking for an allocation failure *at all* is most likely a waste of time.  Interestingly, if you stopped checking for `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` failures, an OOM situation would have the same net effect of `unrecoverable_malloc` (without the log message).

Comment: @SeanBright: Depends on what sort of code your write.  If your code can impact the safety of real people, no, you cannot ignore the possibility of an OOM situation. Doesn't mean that you can do much about it, but you at least know, and you can stop execution.  Also depends on the platform.

Comment: @EdS. fair enough. but when one of the core requirements of your application is to "protect human life," the conversation about safe degradation goes well beyond the trivial "how do we recover if this single allocation fails."  if you work for NASA or Lockheed and you are reading this post, please disregard everything I have said! :-)

Answer (score 4):

> is there any reason why it shouldn't be done?

If your application can afford to exit as soon as an allocation fail, then by all means, make this a function, and incorporate it in the allocation function even.

If you are writing code that needs to be better-behaved than that (for instance a library), you cannot do this because an error code must typically be returned after having freed anything that was successfully allocated.

In this latter case, the pattern looks like:

```
p1 = malloc(…);
if (!p1) goto error;
p2 = malloc(…);
if (!p2) goto free1;
p3 = malloc(…);
if (!p3) goto free2;
…
free2:
free(p2);
free1:
free(p1);
error:
return -1;
```

Comment: I'd normally see every condition jump to the same label, so that the cleanup code would always do `free(p2); free(p1); return -1` since freeing a null pointer is a no-op.

Comment: @Kos That's another possibility, but it does not generalize to other kinds of resources. `fclose(NULL);` is not documented as a no-op, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

That's (almost) fine; as long as you are going to handle the error in the exact same way each time.  However; to my eyes, a function named `nullcheck` which returns nothing and may *exit* the program is, at best, inappropriately named.

Comment: Agreed.  You would be better off with `assert` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Q:Is there any reason to not turn null check after malloc into a function?
A: Yes: Corner case: allocating 0

Returning `NULL` from `malloc()`, `calloc()`, etc in itself is not a certain indication of out-of-memory.

Allocation functions may return `NULL` when the amount requested is `0`.  Alternatively these functions may return a non-`NULL` pointer.

Consider putting `malloc()` and the test into 1 function.

```
void *malloc_check(size_t n) {
  void *p = malloc(n);
  if (p == NULL && n > 0) {
    printf("Memory allocation has failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return p;
}

// or insure `malloc(0)` never occurs.

void *malloc_check(size_t n) {
  if (n == 0) n++;
  void *p = malloc(n);
  if (p == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation has failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return p;
}
```